# DELETE INNER JOIN use LEFT JOIN PHP

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join

How can I delete inner join and use Left Join instead?

I have two tables that are dishinfo and category,

dishinfo has id_cate which is the number of category

for example:

```
id_cate:1
id_cate:1
id_cate:2
```

whereas category table have:

```
id_cate:1 == cate_descrip:dessert
id_cate:2 == cate_decrip:lunch
```

my code:

```
SELECT dishinfo.id_cate,cate_descrip 
FROM dishinfo 
INNER JOIN category 
ON dishinfo.id_cate=category.id_cate;
```

Comment: Do you want to delete records using left join?

Comment: Please provide a sample data before the deletion, and the expected data after.

Comment: JOIN is a way to link together two tables while you are running a query. So no need to delete one join to use another. Just edit your query and use the type of JOIN you need

Answer (score 0):

if you do a simple left join it would be something like:

```
SELECT dishinfo.id_cate, cate_descrip 
FROM dishinfo 
LEFT JOIN category 
ON dishinfo.id_cate = category.id_cate;
```

but this will return every records from dishinfo including those that has id_cate NULL to prevent this you can do like this:

```
SELECT dishinfo.id_cate, cate_descrip 
FROM dishinfo 
LEFT JOIN category ON dishinfo.id_cate = category.id_cate 
WHERE dishinfo.id_cate IS NOT NULL;
```

with the extra condition you will prevent selecting those records that doesn't have id_cate